# Refurbishing an old Alienware Laptop

Tags: laptop

I have an old (2011) Alienware m18x. At this point, it is half dead (both dedicated AMD GPUs died long ago) and something is going on with the internal clock, as it keeps delaying the date after being adjusted, and the keyboard is also dead. Other than that, it still works fine, with its ancient SSD, and the screen still looks great.

As I am not very knowledgeable in computer hardware topics, I would like to ask what is the feasibility of completely changing the internals of the Laptop.
By this I do not mean upgrading GPUs, memory and such, but completely removing the internals and using just the body with a completely new set of components (eg. from a newer laptop, where the components would be up to date, but fit in a smaller form factor).

I understand there might be complications, such as thermals, component positioning and so on. I also understand that this might be much more expensive and complicated than just buying a new Laptop. Regardless, would this project be feasible? What would be the basic things to take into account in doing this?

Comment: Aside from the fact that nothing would fit - just think of how you'd fit keyboard & screen as the largest examples - you'd first have to buy an entire new laptop… which tend to come with a case already. I cannot see the point, even if feasible.

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh yeah, that I know. I just want to know if it would be possible, and how one would go about it.

Comment: No-one is going to be able to design it for you - time to get out the CAD & 3D printer & start making adaptors for everything.